# listing of files and folders of android file system in ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic2, filesystems

i am trying to list all the files and folder present at the external storage of mobile, but unable to get the desired result. i took help from the code but it is not recognising the window object. can anyone help for this.

```js
getFiles(path){
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
    function (fileSystem) {
      var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
      reader.readEntries(
        function (entries) {
          console.log(entries);
        },
        function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    }, function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

I used the filepath plugin but result is not actually what i want.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU6wd.png) also my code is

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Transfer, TransferObject} from '@ionic-native/transfer';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';



declare var cordova:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html',
  providers: [FilePath, Transfer, TransferObject, File]
 
})
export class ContactPage {

  storageDirectory: string = '';
  
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private filePath: FilePath, public platform: Platform, private transfer: Transfer, private file: File){
 
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      
   if(this.platform.is('android')) {
        this.storageDirectory = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
  console.log(this.storageDirectory);
      }
      else {
        // exit otherwise, but you could add further types here e.g. Windows
        return false;
  
      }
    });

 this.filePath.resolveNativePath(this.storageDirectory+'files')
  .then(filePath => console.log("this is my file path" + filePath))
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
 
 
 }
 
}
```

this is not even printing file name on console and how i display the file content on the device screen, please guide me.

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
   import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Transfer, TransferObject} from '@ionic-native/transfer';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html',
 providers: [FilePath, Transfer, TransferObject, File]
})
export class ContactPage {

  storageDirectory: string = '';
  
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private filePath: FilePath, public platform: Platform, private transfer: Transfer, private file: File){
 
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       file.listDir(file.externalDataDirectory,'').then((result)=>{
     console.log(result);
/*result will have an array of file objects with 
file details or if its a directory*/
  for(let file of result){
    if(file.isDirectory == true && file.name !='.' && file.name !='..'){
  // Code if its a folder
 }else if(file.isFile == true){
  // Code if its a file
  let name=file.name // File name
  let path=file.path // File path
    file.getMetadata(function (metadata) {
   let size=metadata.size; // Get file size
      })
 }
    }
  }
})
  
}
}
```

You should use the [@ionic-native/file documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) that should provide you more insight on the usage of the different native scripts.

Comment: above method saying cordova is not defined.

Comment: removed all cordova instances from existing file..now working. Thanks!!

Comment: yes I see this as answer, but this is giving me objects, how do i extract properties from these object. I am getting as [Object object] as an output, and I need to access the Object properties, Please help.

Comment: What are you using for testing an emulator or an actual device ?

Comment: actual android device.

Comment: Are you using chrome://inspect to debug your app coz that would be the easiest to view the properties

Comment: yes i am inspecting it well with chrome://inspect/#devices, and thanks your code patch is working fine. also while accessing path or url, this is not accessible. Giving error ''Property 'path' does not exist on type 'Entry'.''  I am not getting the reason and tried even many combinations like Url, URL etc. Please look it for.

Comment: What does file.name log

Comment: file.name showing file name "dizzy.mp4" but error in file.path.

Comment: okay..finally with the solution..need to use fullPath that will give the path for the file. So closing the answer thread with this..thanks!! Izzo Obella

Comment: Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Home.Html

List Directory

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let printValues of showFile">
  {{printValues}}
</ion-item>
```